# Double integral question area?

Tags: integration

Calculate the integral: $$^{} \iint_{D}dx dy$$ where $D :=\{(x,y):\ x^2+y^2\le a^2\}$.

So this is obviously a circle, but how do I use it to integrate?

Comment: It's a disk, not a circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without polar coordinates but suffering a little more. The integral is

$$\int\limits_{-a}^adx\int\limits_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dy=2\int\limits_{-a}^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx\stackrel{\text{even func.}}=4\int\limits_0^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx=$$

$$=4a\int\limits_0^a\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xa\right)^2}\,dx=:I$$

and now substitution:

$$\frac xa=\sin u\implies dx=a\cos u\,du\;,\;\;\begin{cases}x=a\implies u=\frac\pi2\\{}\\x=0\implies u=0 \end{cases}$$

Thus

$$I=4a^2\int\limits_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos^2u\,=\left.4a^2\frac{u+\sin u\cos u}2\right|_0^{\pi/2}du=4a^2\cdot\frac\pi 4=\pi a^2$$

Comment: Don Antonio muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, @asfd: con mucho gusto.

Answer (score 3):

Using polar coordinates
$$
x=r\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\theta,
$$
we have
$$
\iint_D\,dxdy=\iint_{[0,a]\times[0,2\pi]}r\,drd\theta=\frac{2\pi }{2}a^2=\pi a^2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating:
$$
\int_{-a}^a\int_{-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} dx dy
$$
we simplify our calculations by converting to polar coordinates ($x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$):
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^ardrd\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^ardr
= \left[\theta\right]_0^{2\pi}\left[\dfrac{r^2}{2}\right]_0^a = 2\pi\cdot \dfrac{a^2}{2}=\pi a^2
$$
which makes sense, since this is the formula for the area of a circle of radius $a$. That is:
$$
\iint_D dxdy
$$
represents the area of the region $D$.